# Outlook Add-In in Store validation process: Do changes in code trigger re-validation?

Tags: outlook-addin, office-store

I've submitted an Outlook add-in to the Office Store and it's in the validation process.

I have observed the status go from Release Readiness back to Validation.

My question is whether the Office Store validation process is at all affected by server-side changes to the add-in, seeing as the "meat" of the addin is hosted on one's own server. Does pushing out an update to the HTML displayed in the add-in in any way invalidate a previous validation?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you are new user, I recommend you read ["How to Ask a Good Question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This is not a question the community can provide an answer for.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-Microsoft I rephrased this as more general question. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a big of a grey area. In general the answer is no, making simple changes to the web app/add-in does not require you to re-submit a new manifest version.

More substantial changes should be re-submitted to ensure it is tested against the latest validation requirements. This ensures your add-in is working with the latest Office revisions and telegraphs to users both that your add-in can be trusted and that it remains in active development.

For changes to core functionality, there is an explicit [validation policy](https://dev.office.com/officestore/docs/validation-policies). Section 7.3 explains that changes to the add-in that impacts the accuracy of the Store description need to be resubmitted:

> Your app or add-in's title, description, and images must reflect its functionality, and may not mislead the user. If you make changes to your app or add-in such that the functionality does not match the description, you must resubmit your app or add-in.